# How do I format a date with a locale preferred date format with the actual month name?

Tags: php, yii

I have a project using [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/) that is built to support multiple languages. Using [setlocale](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) I can do the following:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'en_US', 'English');
echo strftime('%x', mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 25, 2014));

// outputs '12/25/2014'


setlocale(LC_TIME, 'fr_FR', 'French_France')
echo strftime('%x', mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 25, 2014));

// outputs '25/12/2014'
```

This is almost what I need, however, I want to print out the actual name of the month in the preferred format not just the numbers. For example, for US English I'd like it to output:

> December 25, 2014

And for French I'd like to output:

> 25 décembre 2014

This has to work for whatever locale is provided (multiple countries) using the specific formatting rules for that locale, French in France and English are just examples. Is there a similar "automatic" way to do this with Yii or just php? Or do I need to save a formatting string along with the locale (not my preffered option)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yii's application object has a [`dateFormatter`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#dateFormatter-detail) attribute that gives you access to a [`CDateFormatter`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDateFormatter) object; you can use this object to [format dates](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDateFormatter#format-detail) according to the application's [current language](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#language-detail).

You can set this language inside your [entry script](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.entry), or you can defer it until some later point (still before you start generating content of course) such as your base controller's `init` method.

An example:

```
$time = mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 25, 2014);
$app = Yii::app();
$app->language = 'fr_fr'; // yii uses all lowercase

echo $app->dateFormatter->formatDateTime($time, 'long', null);
```

In the above snippet, `'long'` corresponds to the date format `d MMMM y` for the specified locale (Yii uses the [CLDR specification](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) for format strings; this preset is the equivalent of the `%x` specification in Yii terms) and `null` instructs the formatter to not include time information in the result at all.

You could also manually specify the format yourself if you wanted to:

```
echo $app->dateFormatter->format('d MMMM y', $time);
```

Comment: The Yii documentation don't have any examples so could you show an example of this? Also I can't use the entry script to set the language because the same codebase is used for multiple languages/regions (which is pulled from a database), can the locale be set on the fly (such as in the init function of the base Controller class?)

Comment: @Scott: I expanded the answer to address your follow-up questions.

Comment: Ahh almost there. My output for french is coming out as '25 dÃ©cembre 2014 00:00:00' I'm assuming the messed up characters have something to do with the encoding? It is set to the default UTF-8 which I would assume would work.

Comment: @Scott: I 'm not sure what you did exactly, but it's obvious from the output that it's not being treated as UTF-8. If you put the `echo` inside any view it should work.

Comment: Yeah, it's gotta be something with Yii because if I output strftime below it that looks correct. I opened the fr_fr.php file in the framework/i18n/data folder just to make sure it was saved correctly and it looks fine there as well. Do I need to explicitly set UTF-8 somewhere in the config/main.php file? Yii::app()->charset returns 'UTF-8'.

Comment: `strftime` does not output UTF-8 with that locale so it would certainly appear OK. Again, I 'm not sure why you are not getting correct output. You are doing something wrong but impossible to tell what exactly.

Comment: Yup, I just put the code in a different project and it worked as intended so obviously there is something weird somewhere else. I'll track it down. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In Yii 2:

```
// set locale
Yii::$app->language = 'fr-FR';

// ouput locale date
Yii::$app->formatter->asDate(timestampOrValidDate, [format]);
Yii::$app->formatter->asDate(time()); // outputs "18 Oct 2019" for en-GB
Yii::$app->formatter->asDate('2019-12-31'); // outputs "31.12.2019" for german locale
```

See the [guide](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/output-formatting).